# How to sort a 2D array row and column wise?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to sort a 2-dimensional array both row and column wise. I'm able to sort it row wise but however I'm not able to do it column wise. I'm trying to do it the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void sort_rows(int *arr,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
       int key=arr[i];
       int j=i-1;
       while(j>=0 && key<arr[j])
       {
           arr[j+1]=arr[j];
           j--;
       }
        arr[j+1]=key;
    }
}
void sort_column(int arr[][3],int size)
{
    int i,j;
    int key,k;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<size;j++)
        {
            key=arr[j][i];
            k=j-1;
            while(k>=0 && arr[k][i]>key)
            {
                arr[k+1][i]=arr[k][i];
                k--;
            }
            arr[k+1][i]=key;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[][3]={{9,8,7},{6,5,4},{3,2,1}};
    int i,j,size;
    size=((sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0][0])/(sizeof(arr[0])/sizeof(arr[0][0])))); //calculates the size of each row.
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        sort_rows(arr[i],sizeof(arr[i])/sizeof(arr[i][0]));
    }
    size=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); //calculates the size of each column.
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        sort_column(arr[i][size],size);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I used selection sort to sort rows and column. I know that my approach to sort it column wise is wrong. I'm getting this error in my code: `passing argument 1 of 'sort_column' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]`
Please help me correcting this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error the compiler gives you is telling you exactly what the problem is. When you call `sort_column(arr[i][size], size)`, `arr[i][size]` evaluates to an int. However, the first argument to `sort_column()`, as you have defined it, is a 2D array. Therefore, the types do not match.

Comment: So how to overcome this?

Comment: The problem is you have written a function that takes arguments of certain types and are trying to call that function with arguments that have types not matching those you specified. How might you go about resolving this?

Comment: I think by changing function prototype to `void sort_column(int **arr,int row_size,int coumn_size);`

Comment: but I'm still not able to do it using 'void sort_column(int **arr,int column_size);`

Comment: I did it using `void sort_column(int (*arr)[3],int coumn_size);`
I'm getting the correct output but I'm still getting the same warning.

Comment: `int (*arr)[3]` is a pointer to an array of ints. If you're passing an int to that function, it is still incorrect. If you're not understanding why this is problematic, you should take time to thoroughly reconsider all aspects of your design and why you chose them.

Comment: Thank you, I finally found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in the calling expression  `sort_column(arr[i][size],size);` which calls `sort_column` to sort it column wise. The correct expression is `sort_column(arr,size);`. Check this link for the complete code: http://ideone.com/iLeFfr

Answer (score -3):

```
import java.util.*;

public sort 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int m=sc.nextInt();
        int a[][]=new int[n][m];enter code here
        for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=m-1;j++)
            {
                a[i][j]=sc.nextInt();//TAKE INPUT
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
        {
             Arrays.sort(a[i]);//  SORT RAW-WISE
        }

        for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
            {
                int t=a[i][j];
                a[i][j]=a[j][i];
                a[j][i]=t;
            }
        }                     //TRANSPOSE IT SO RAW BECOMES COLOUM AND VISE A VERSA

        for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
        {
             Arrays.sort(a[i]);//  SORT RAW-WISE(COLOUM)
        }

        for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
            {
                int t=a[i][j];
                a[i][j]=a[j][i];
                a[j][i]=t;
            }
       }                    // FOR OBTANING ORIGINAL ONE

        for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=m-1;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
            }
          System.out.println();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please pay attention to the tags of a question. This question is tagged with the language tag for C. Your answer however is not C, it's Java.